# DigiKey and others are incorrect about cutoff frequency for an LC filter

Tags: passive-filter

(At least I believe this is true.)

If you Google "LC filter" and "cutoff frequency" you will probably see the formula 1/(2π sqrt(LC)). An example would be this online calculator at DigiKey:

https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-low-pass-and-high-pass-filter

[image]

However, I believe this is the *resonant* frequency, not the -3 dB cutoff frequency:

[image]

So here's my "proof." The voltage transfer function Vout/Vin is:

[image]

The resonant frequency fr is where Vout/Vin gets very large. In other words, when the denominator goes to zero:

[image]

The resonant frequency is **not** the -3 dB cutoff frequency as so many articles & websites claim. The cutoff frequency (fc) is defined as the frequency where the output power is half the input power:

[image]

Please check my math, but I'm pretty confident it is correct. If so, I wonder how many designers have been using the wrong formula for the cutoff frequency for an LC filter?

(Having said all of that, I understand that the analysis for a practical implementation would also have to take into account the source impedance and load impedance. None-the-less, you can still come up with a transfer function for just this circuit, along with a resonant frequency and -3 dB frequency. My point is that DigiKey and others are referring to the resonant frequency as the -3 dB frequency, which is obviously incorrect.)

Comment: Digi-key's *bode plot image* shows a low-pass filter type response. For an LC filter to have a response approaching this type, at least *one* resistance is required, so it must become an RLC - and the equation must include R as well as L,C. Like you, I find Digi-key's page misleading...or incorrect.

Comment: Yes, the Bode plot on the DigiKey website is definitely incorrect, in that it doesn't show Vout/Vin spiking at the resonant frequency. But I am more concerned that they (and many others) are incorrectly using the formula for the resonant frequency when they're talking about the cutoff frequency. As shown in my post, the formula for the cutoff frequency is different that the formula for the resonant frequency.

Comment: Is there a question here? Seems like more of a rant, why here instead of taking it up with them?

Comment: GodJihyo, before I contact DigiKey, I would like someone to look over my math and concur that I am correct.

Comment: In the interests of de-duplication and cross-pollination, this was also posted on this community: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/digikey-and-others-are-incorrect-about-cutoff-frequency-for-an-lc-filter/msg5242309/?topicseen#new

Answer (score 5):

The equation:$$f_N=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$ represents the natural frequency of any second order system/circuit. It may or may not represent an actual frequency of oscillation and should be considered a second order parameter.

In the case of a second order series filter, the natural frequency and the resonant frequency are the same occuring where \$Z_C=-Z_L\$. It does not matter what signal is considered the output.

A series under damped RLC low-pass filter (output across the capacitor) has a peak in the frequency response which is often (correctly or incorrectly) called the resonant frequency. This peaking always occurs at a value \$f_{LO}<f_N\$ the natural frequency

A series under damped RLC high-pass filter (output across the inductot) has a peak in the frequency response which is often (correctly or incorrectly) also called the resonant frequency. This peaking always occurs at a value \$f_{HI}>f_N\$ the natural frequency

As the series resistance \$R\rightarrow 0\$ the Q of the circuit increases and these two peaks converge to \$f_N\$ as \$Q\rightarrow\infty\$. So for the LC circuit from DIGI-KEY the natural frequency can be used to approximate \$f_{LO}\$ and \$f_{HI}\$.

The formula for the cutoff frequency is correct. When taking a square root, the result can be positive or negative. In this case only one is correct leading to the result:$$f_c=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{LC}}=f_N\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$$

So the DIGI-KEY calculator notation is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Russel! So my equations are correct for an unloaded LC filter?

Comment: Yes @Craft_Ohio

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after some further thought I think I understand this better now.

At the resonant peak there is a phase change from 0 degrees to -180 degrees. This can be seen in the initial transfer function where it gives negative values for Vo/Vin for values of w greater than 1/sqrt(LC).

So, I would have found it easier to understand your working if you had calculated the -3 dB frequency by equating the transfer function to -0.707 and solving for w. This would have given you the correct expression without just changing the sign of the numerator for which I initially struggled to understand the reason.

So, I agree with your expression for the -3 dB frequency.

However, a cut-off frequency is often, but not always defined as the -3 dB frequency and perhaps DigiKey and others are defining the cutoff frequency as the resonant peak frequency rather than the -3 dB frequency. An example of an alternative definition of a cutoff frequency would be a Chebychev filter where the cutoff frequency is defined as the frequency where the magnitude response leaves the pass band rather than the -3 dB frequency.

Comment: user350400, I didn't show this, but the (1-ω²LC)² needs to be changed to (ω²LC-1)² in order to make the number in the square root positive. So my final equation is correct, and it perfectly predicts the -3 dB frequency when the transfer function is plotted.

Answer (score 1):

> Having said all of that, I understand that the analysis for a practical implementation would also have to take into account the source impedance and load impedance

Your intuition is correct: if the circuit is intended as a low pass filter, then the designer would try to minimize Q to avoid having a huge resonance spike which can cause undesirable effects like overvoltage or amplifier saturation. This requires resistance for damping, not just L and C.

If source and load impedance are known, for example in a 50 ohm environment, it is much more efficient to use these for damping. Loss in the source resistance is unavoidable, and loss in the load resistance is actual power transferred to the load, so it's not really a loss.

Besides, with passive filters, you can't ignore source and load impedance. They're part of the circuit.

So the problem with the digikey page you quoted is that it misses context. It assumes (without saying it) that you want a well damped response. It shows a bode plot that looks like that, although it's not clear if it's log or linear on the Y axis. It's also not clear if the response shown is one of the classics like Butterworth, Bessel, Critically damped or not... With the same LC values, each of these filter recipes has a slightly different -3dB cutoff. Then it displays the LC resonance frequency as -3dB cutoff which is incorrect. Basically everything is wrong.

If you want a usable filter design tool, you can try [Microcap](https://gotroot.ca/spectrum/www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.html):

[image]

Comment: Thanks bobflux. Yea, the Bode plot is wrong on DigiKey's page. But I  guess I am more bothered by the fact they're calling 1/(2π sqrt(LC)) the -3 dB cutoff frequency, which is completely wrong. That's the resonant frequency, not the -3 dB cutoff frequency.

Comment: Digi-Key is not guilty. They only publish manufacturers claims.

Answer (score 0):

so one thing to keep in mind is that the -3dB freq means that it is halved, every 3dB is a doubling of amplitude or intensity, and thereby every 3dB reduction is a halving. I think it is more of a representation issue utilizing disparate quanta or systems of measurement leading to confusion.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).